# numpy.random.choice() not functionning right

Tags: python, numpy

This is a part of my code:

```
def generateInstruction(Seed, Probability):

    random.seed(Seed)
    random.seed()

    NumberOfAddresses = random.randint(10, 40) 
    ListOfAdresses = list()
    Operations = [1,0]
    Probabilities = [Probability, 1-Probability]


    Var = random.randint(0, NumberOfAddresses)
    if Var not in ListOfAdresses:
        Op=0 
        Instruction =  str(Op) + "\t" + str(Var )+ "\n" 
        ListOfAdresses.append(Var)

    else:
        Op = numpy.random.choice(Operations, 1, True, Probabilities)
        Instruction = str(Op) + "\t" + str(Var )+ "\n"
    return Instruction
```

This function is intended to generate an instruction with 2 parts an operation `op` and a variable `var`, if the variable is appearing for the first time the operation will have to be equal to **0**. Otherwise it can be either **0** or **1** according to a certain probability that I pass through the command line.

Later in the main, I call this function in a loop and the variables are kept in a list `listOfAdresses` for verification. The problem is in output, my sequence is all with operations that are 0 although some variables appear more than once, this makes me question the **else** part of the function but I can't see what's wrong with it. Any remarks?

This is the code where I call it:

```
def main():

    random.seed(2)
    K = random.randint(200, 2000) 
    print(K)
    P=list()
    if (len(sys.argv) > 2) :
        for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
            P.append(float(sys.argv[i]))

        f= open('Trace.txt' , 'w+')
        Seed = float(sys.argv[1])
        for j in range(0 , len(sys.argv)-2) : 
            Probability = P[j]# there something with this index
            for Iteration in range(K*j, K*(j+1)):
                Instr = generateInstruction(Seed, Probability)
                f.write(Instr)
        #f.close()
    else:
        print('Params Error')
```

The sequence is divided to segments every segment has a different probability as input. All probabilities are passed in the command line.

Comment: Also, how should we call this function? What arguments give the behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: title fixed... I don't understand your question!!

Comment: I'm asking for example values for `Seed` and `Probability`

Comment: seed is just any int and probability is a float between 0 and 1, they are passed through the command line. an example of my run commands would be: python3 trace-generator.py 34 0.23 0.43 0.76

Comment: show us how you call the function in for loop, because if you use same seed in the for loop than you need the loop to include the list of the seed ... otherwise for example if you call in for loop same Seed than you just reassign the same seed

Comment: You do not maintain any state between function calls. There is no loop _within_ the function body, and `ListOfAdresses` is initialised to an empty list on every function call, so `if Var not in ListOfAdresses:` is always `True`

Comment: you're right. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `else` branch of your code never executes. This is because you do not maintain any record of previous values in `ListOfAdresses`. Instead, each time the function is called, you reinitialise `ListOfAdresses` to an empty list.

This means that:

```
if Var not in ListOfAdresses:
```

Is always `True` and therefore, you never actually call `numpy.random.choice()`